# How to use Multidimensional array in AngularJS?

Tags: angularjs, arrays, multidimensional-array

I am trying to construct 2D array and access items for each array in  div inside html. So I would like to have array like this,

```
    ctrl.interfaces = [
      ['driver1', 'driver2'],
      ['driver3', 'driver4'],
      ['driver5'],
      ['driver6', 'driver7', 'driver8']
    ]
```

So right now I am using angular.forEach on ctrl.interfaces to modify the values in following way

```
    ctrl.interfaces[responseFromLoop1] += responseFromLoop2
```

But now if I call `alert(ctrl.interfaces[responseFromLoop1])` , I see undefinedValue1Value2. The Value1Value2 are correct, but I am unable to find the exact way to add elements to the inner array. 
I would also appreciate the being shown the way this 2D array should be used in html. Thanks folks!

Here, is piece of code in the question. 
http://paste.openstack.org/show/612167/

Comment: Is your end goal, just to display a multi-dimensional array on the UI? What are you trying to achieve with `ctrl.interfaces[responseFromLoop1] += responseFromLoop2`?

Comment: Please post complete code, it's difficult to see what you are trying to do here.

Comment: Yes, so my end goal is if the label is 'power' then the drop down option will list the interfaces for power in the above code it should be 'driver1' and 'driver2'. If the label is 'inspect' then the dropdown should show 'driver3' and 'driver4'

Comment: Adrian smith, okay let me try to post some more code to help you guys better understand it. Actually it is a part of big project I am working on at work. Not sure, how much shall i put here

Comment: @CodeWarrior,  update the description with the code

Comment: @AdrianSmith: updated

Comment: I have i think got the logic on the AngularJS side, but now working how to show 2D array content in html. My pastebin above will give you the snippet of the code on AngularJS side. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Here is an example of printing out a two-dimensional array in Angular.

```js
angular.module('app', [])
  .controller('MainCtrl', ['$scope', function($scope) {
    $scope.rows = [
      [1, 2, 3],
      [4, 5, 6],
      [7, 8, 9]
    ];
  }]);
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.2.23/angular.min.js"></script>
<div ng-app="app" ng-controller="MainCtrl">
  <div ng-repeat="row in rows">
    row: {{$index}}
    <div ng-repeat="element in row">
      {{element}}
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Is $index built-in property?

Comment: Yes, $index is provided inside of ng-repeat directives.

Comment: Nope, that is not showing me anything. Here is what i have in my HTML http://paste.openstack.org/show/612168/.

Comment: That paste is very unclear as to what you are trying to accomplish. First of all, {$ $} isn't Angular syntax as all as far as I know. Also, in your second ngRepeat you seem to be trying to do some sort of nested loop, which isn't valid syntax. ngRepeat onyl supports `item in items` style looping. If you want a nested loop, put one directive inside another like i did in the snippet above.

Comment: For more details read the documentation for ngRepeat here: https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/directive/ngRepeat

Comment: Sorry for unclear snippet. I am finding a good way to show you how I want the data in the array. But, not finding how to show you that. Okay and thanks for the info that ng-repeat don't take nested loop. I will try to do as you did in the above snippet. Thanks for patience

Comment: No problem. Angular can have a steep learning curve, but is a joy once you get used to it.

Comment: Yes, :). But how can i have another directive inside <option></option> tag?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/146298/discussion-between-user3339691-and-adrian-smith).